# Why does the definition of $\text {graph of } T$ imply that $Tu+Tv=T(u+v)$ in Problem 1 of Section 3.E of Linear Algebra Done Right (Axler)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem 1 of Section 3.E of Linear Algebra Done Right (Axler) is the following.

> Suppose $T$ is a function from $V$ to $W$. The graph of $T$ is the subset of $V \times W$ defined by
> $$
> \text {graph of } T=\{(v, T v) \in V \times W \mid v \in V\} .
> $$
> Prove that $T$ is a linear map if and only if the graph of $T$ is a subspace of $V \times W$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $\text {graph of } T$ is a subspace of $V\times W$ and let $(u,Tu),(v,Tv)\in\text {graph of } T$. Since $\text {graph of } T$ is a subspace of $V \times W$ it must be closed under addition (by 1.34). Hence $(u,Tu)+(v,Tv)=(u+v,T(u+v))\in\text {graph of } T$. So far so good.

I couldn't figure out the next step and consulted a solution which stated that by the definition of $\text {graph of } T$, $Tu+Tv=T(u+v)$. Hence the additivity condition is satisfied. I'm probably overlooking something obvious but I don't see why the definition of $\text {graph of } T$ implies that $Tu+Tv=T(u+v)$. In my mind we only know that $(u,Tu)$ and $(v,Tv)$, as well as $(u+v,T(u+v))$ are in $\text {graph of } T$ but not that $Tu+Tv=T(u+v)$ [since we're only assuming about $T$ that it is a function from $V$ to $W$]. Thanks for considering my question!

Comment: If a pair $(x,y)$ belongs to the graph, then $y=Tx$ by definition. Apply this to the pair $(u,Tu)+(v,Tv)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that the definition of the graph implies that for each $v\in V$ there exists one and only one element $w\in W$ such that $(v,w)$ is in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition:** Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and let $f\subseteq A\times B$. Then $f$ is said to be a **function from $A$ to $B$** if the following two conditions hold:

(1) For each $x\in A$ there is a $y\in B$ such that $(x,y)\in f.$

(2) If $(x,y)\in f$ and $(x,z)\in f,$ then $y=z$.

Due to condition (2), if $$(x_1,f(x_1))+(x_2,f(x_2))=(x_1+x_2,f(x_1)+f(x_2))\in f$$ and $$(x_1+x_2,f(x_1+x_2))\in f,$$ then $f(x_1)+f(x_2)=f(x_1+x_2)$.